# Python: Continue Loop

Tags: python, continue

I use the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup (open("43rd-congress.htm"))

final_link = soup.p.a
final_link.decompose()

trs = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:
    for link in tr.find_all('a'):
         fulllink = link.get ('href')
         print fulllink #print in terminal to verify results

tds = tr.find_all("td")

try: 
        names = str(tds[0].get_text())
    years = str(tds[1].get_text())
    positions = str(tds[2].get_text())
    parties = str(tds[3].get_text())
    states = str(tds[4].get_text())
    congress = tds[5].get_text()

 except:
    print "bad tr string"
    continue 


    print names, years, positions, parties, states, congress
```

And I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop.
```

Why is that? I have checked indentations and colons. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your code's indentation doesn't look right. Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: `continue` keyword should be inside a loop. What do you want it to do here ?

Comment: @yakiang I want to have it print "names, years, positions, parties, states congress." However, when I remove continue I get a print error on line 28.

Does that make sense?

I am using this tutorial...http://jeriwieringa.com/blog/2012/11/04/beautiful-soup-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: What exception are you getting?  You're just catching everything that comes up, so it makes it really tough to see what's truly going south in the code.  Typically, using a `continue` is a smell for me unless there's a convincing reason; could you share what the exception you're guarding against would be?

Comment: @RobB. I suppose your `print names,years etc` is inside that `except`, if the program runs here, that means sth's wrong in your `try`, and some of the variables (`names,years` etc ) must be wrong,too.Thus you cannot print them out. Hope I was understood :)

Comment: @Makoto
I'm trying to guard against this. It would tell the program to move on to the next item if there is an error in parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things.

First, [`continue`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) is for use within a while or for loop to tell the loop to skip to the next iteration. Where you've used it, in a try/except block, doesn't work. You might be thinking of [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass), but you only need that if you are trying to do something like:

```
try:
    # Code with potential error
except ErrortoCatch:
    pass
```

Where you want to have an indented block, but not do anything in it. Here, that means you want to catch the exception, but not do anything about it.

You have some indentation errors and weirdness, like the fact that names is indented an extra level accidentally. This is probably because you have mixed tabs (which expand to 8 spaces) and spaces (which you should be using 4 of). [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says you should use 4 space to indent, advice you should follow.

What is *probably* causing your error is your use of a bare `except:`, which is almost NEVER a good idea. When you are using try/except blocks, you should always know what error you are looking for so you don't accidentally mask a real error when you are just trying to handle some specific exception. Notably, `except:` also catches stuff like `KeyboardInterrupt`, which you really, really, don't want to catch.

What I think is happening is one of the operations in your `try` block is causing an error that makes the variable unprintable for some reason. This could be A LOT of things, so you should specify what error you are trying to handle in your `except` statement and then figure out what other error is popping up that you need to fix.

Also, you should never have spaces between a function names and its call, e.g. `link.get ('href')` => `link.get('href')`.

Answer (score 0):

[`continue`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) is only allowed within a for or while loop. You have put it in the `except`. I think you may make the wrong indentation or misunderstand `continue`.